# Correct syntax for partial specialization with smart pointers

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have this function

```cpp
template<class A, class B>
std::shared_ptr<A> Foo(const B& obj) { ... }
```

And I want to provide a convenient function that also gets smart pointer (`shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`) instead of references. Something like this:

```cpp
template<class A, class B>
std::shared_ptr<A> Foo(const std::shared_ptr<B>& obj) {
  return Foo<A>(const_cast<const B&>(*obj));
}
```

It only works like that if I overload `Foo` to get `shared_ptr` as a parameter. However, I want to write it as a partial specialization. I also tried

```cpp
template<class A>
template<class B>
std::shared_ptr<A> Foo(const std::shared_ptr<B>& obj) { ... }
```

What is the correct syntax for this partial specialization?

Comment: Function templates cannot be partially specialised. Write it as a class template with a static member function, and a single generic function template that forwards to the class.

Comment: @Andrew an overload should suffice (due to partial ordering)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Indeed it should.

Comment: Why do you want it as a partial specialization?

Comment: Oh, they can't! I'll accept it as the answer. @Yakk, because I thought it made more sense than an overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *partially* specialize a function template. However, you can safely rely on your current solution.
Having two function overloads:

```
template<class A, class B>
std::shared_ptr<A> Foo(const B& obj);

template<class A, class B>
std::shared_ptr<A> Foo(const std::shared_ptr<B>& obj);
```

the latter is considered by the compiler as *more specialized* * in overload resolution due to partial ordering, hence, it gets picked whenever a matching `std::shared_ptr<T>` is passed in as an argument.

---

* `const std::shared_ptr<B>&` is more specialized than `const B&`, because for some unique type `Unique`, `B` in `const B&` can be deduced from `const std::shared_ptr<Unique>&`, but in a counter scenario, for a `const std::shared_ptr<B>&` parameter with a `const Unique&` argument deduction of `B` fails.